# parse an xml file then pass that file to another parser if the first tag is the one i want

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, saxparser

My main parser looks like this...

```
public void MainParser(InputStream is) {

    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        final InputStream finalIs = is;
        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

            boolean item = false, employee = false;

            public String current_parent = "";

            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)throws SAXException {

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Item")) {
                    current_parent = "Item";
                    item = true;
                }

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee") ) {
                    current_parent = "Employee";
                    employee = true;
                }

                if(item)
                {
                    ParseItemFromXML(finalIs);
                }
                else if(employee)
                {

                }

            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName,String qName) throws SAXException {

            }

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

            }
        };

        saxParser.parse(is, handler);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

then after it reads the first tag it passes the input stream to another parser(ParseItemfromXml) but so far the other parser doesn't read the inputstream that was passed to it...i don't know what the problem is can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why you are using 2 parser class if you can parse whole data with one parser. Just parse data that you needed and extract from tag and ignore other

Comment: @Abhinav because the files am parsing are huge and all of them have different starting tag so i need two parsers(one to identify the first tag and the others so that they could parse the right xml)

Comment: still you can manage that in a single parser. Parser accepts InputStream and if you extract data from file still you need InputStream to provide to next parser. So you have to manage all these thing in single parser and to difference each data you have tags

Comment: okay thanks i'll try that ,but it gonna make it a huge single method